# Python .iloc error trying to input values into dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

From my df which has a huge amount of rows I attempt to physically enter some values for some of the "NaN". My code is below:

```
pamap2_df["heartrate"].iloc[0:4]=100
```

It does the task, however, It also throws this back in my face:

```
C:\Users\the-e\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1637: 
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df['some_col'].iloc[:4]` is so called index chaining, and its behaviour is unpredictable. I recommend **reading the link in the error for details**

For updating the data, it is recommended that you use a single `.loc` or `iloc` for both column/index:

```
col_idx = pamap2_df.columns.get_loc('heartrate')
pamap2_df.iloc[:4, col_idx] = 100
```

or:

```
idx = pamap2_df.index[:4]
pamap2_df.loc[idx, 'heartrate'] = 100
```

**Note** the error might still persist if your `pamap2_df` is a slice of another dataframe. For example:

```
pamap2_df = df[df['Age'] < some_threshold]

idx = pamap2_df.index[:4]

# this will raise a warning / failure
pamap2_df.loc[idx, 'heartrate'] = 100

# this will do
df.loc[idx, 'heartrate'] = 100
```

Comment: Thank you, first col_idx changed the row not column but the second one did the trick thank you very much :)

Comment: @Noah Yes, I messed it up. Corrected. Thanks. Also, if it helps, please upvote/accept the answer for future users that might have the same problem as you do.